# Paper, Rock and Scissors

Tags: python-2.7

**This CODE is incomplete**
Input

The human player enters the number of points required for a win. During the play of the game   the human player selects whether to play a rock, paper, or scissors by using the keyboard. The human player may also end the game by pressing the Control-D sequence at any time. (Ending the game early does not allow a winner to be determined if the human player is ahead.)

Output

The program will display the winner of each roshambo round along with the running score. At the conclusion of the game, the computer will display the overall winner and the final score.

Sample session

Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!

How many points are required for a win? 3

Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? r
Human: rock    Computer: paper        Computer wins!

Score: Human 0   Computer 1
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? r

Human: rock    Computer: scissors     Human wins!

Score: Human 1   Computer 1
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? p

Human: paper   Computer: paper        A draw

```
print "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!"  
import random  

n=1  
while n:   
     x = int(raw_input("How many points are required for a win? "))   
     y = raw_input("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? ")
     z1 = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
     z = random.choice(z1)
     if y=='r':
          print "Human: Rock  Computer: " + z
          if z=='Rock':
               print "A draw"
          if z=='Paper':
               print "Computer wins!"
          if z=='Scissors':
               print "Human wins!"   

     elif y=='p':       
          print "Human: Paper Computer: " + z  
          if z=='Paper':   
               print "A draw"  
          if z=='Rock':   
               print "Human wins!"   
          if z=='Scissors':   
               print "Computer wins!"      

     elif y=='s':   
          print "Human: Scissors Coputer: " + z   
          if z=='Scissors':   
               print "A draw"   
          if z=='Paper':'   
               print "Human wins!"   
          if z=='Rock':   
               print "Computer wins!"    

raw_input("Press<enter>")
```

And my output is like:Its NOT working after the first loop.

Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!
How many points are required for a win? 3
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (s)cissors? r
Human: Rock  Computer: Rock
A draw

How many points are required for a win? r
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "temp5.py", line 6, in 
        x = int(raw_input("How many points are required for a win? "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'r'
**How could I make my code short and efficient. I could you please suggest how to define functions for this program and use inbuilt methods**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the problem is you entered input which makes no sense. It asked for a number of points, and you entered a letter.

If you want to make it handle such user errors gracefully, ask that.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, understandable. Thats what I want to know, how can I use the number entered by the user to loop till the point equals that number. And thats one of the reasons why my code is still incomplete.

Comment: Ah, I see. The first thing you need to do is to move that question OUTSIDE the loop, because it should only be asked once. The contents of a loop is for things which should be repeated, and that question is not such a thing. Then, you need to keep a record of how many points have been scored.